# The distribution function for for the sum of variables which follow a multivariate normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

Suppose we have two random variables that follow a multivariate normal distribution,

$[x,y]\sim MVN([a,b],
\begin{bmatrix}
\rho_1 & \rho_3 \\
\rho_3 & \rho_2 
\end{bmatrix})$

Then what is the distribution for the sum of x and y?

That is,

$z=x+y \sim N(?,?)$

Surely, $N(a+b,\rho_1+\rho_2)$ does not seem right, since we need to consider the correlation between x and y. But what is the correct way to incorporate this correlation aspect into the final distribution?

Comment: Typing in "variance of the sum of two random variables" in your favorite search engine should quickly give you the answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Correlated_random_variables has the answer.